# insert a value based on certain criteria in attendance sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am putting together a attendance sheet for my workplace. Its going to be partly automated, when a user enters his phone number in the input box his attendance is marked for the day, there is also a input box for the date i.e. just the date not month and year. 
Structure of the excel sheet: 2 columns have name and phone number respectively and rest are 1-31 days of the month. 
so when a user enter a phone number and date a P (for present) appears under the date column in the same row as the phone number.
Problem : the cell that is being selected by the code is the header which has the dates from 1-31
where am i going wrong?
Please Help.
Thank You

```
Sub Find_mobilenumber()
Dim FindString As String
Dim FindString1 As String
Dim Rng As Range
FindString = InputBox("Enter Your Mobile Number")
FindString1 = InputBox("Enter todays Date - e.g 21  for 21/03/2015")
If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
If Trim(FindString1) <> "" Then
With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D:D") 'searches all of column D
With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("7:7") 'searches all of column 7
    Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString1, _
                    After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False)
    If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
        Application.Goto Rng, True 'value found
        If Cell.Value = FindString Goto

        MsgBox "Client Checked In"
    Else
        MsgBox "Client Not Registered" 'value not found
    End If
End With
 End With
 End If
      End If
        End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start a With block here, but do nothing with it

```
With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D:D")
```

I presume this is where you meant to check the D column for mobile numbers?

How about this revision?

```
Sub Find_mobilenumber()

Dim FindString As String
Dim FindString1 As String
Dim PhoneRng As Range
Dim Rng As Range

FindString = InputBox("Enter Your Mobile Number")
FindString1 = InputBox("Enter todays Date - e.g 21  for 21/03/2015")

If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then

    If Trim(FindString1) <> "" Then

        With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D:D") 'searches for phone no in column D

                Set PhoneRng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                              After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                              LookIn:=xlValues, _
                              LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                              SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                              SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                              MatchCase:=False)

        End With

        With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("7:7") 'searches all of column 7

            Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString1, _
                          After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                          LookIn:=xlValues, _
                          LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                          MatchCase:=False)
        End With


        On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

            Intersect(Rng.EntireColumn, PhoneRng.EntireRow).Value = "P"
            MsgBox ("Client Checked In")

    End If

End If

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:

MsgBox ("Client Not Registered")

End Sub
```

Comment: Just a quesstion
how could i put the input box in a loop so that after entering the "P" in the relevant box it returns again for mobile number and date

Comment: Depends how you want to eventually stop the inputbox from reloading. You could start with 'Do until Findstring = "QUIT", with a 'Loop' before 'Exit Sub' then the input box will keep returning until you type QUIT in the mobilenumber prompt. You will need a 'Resume Next' in the ErrorHandler to ensure it continues when after 'Client Not Registered' MsgBox.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than nesting `With...End With` statements, you can break the search into two easier-to-describe steps: (1) Finding the appropriate row, and (2) Finding the appropriate column. Let's say your design looks like this:

[image: an example layout]

You could adjust your script to populate the "Present" table like so:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Find_mobilenumber()

Dim strMobileNumber As String, strDayOfMonth As String
Dim rngMobileNumbers As Range, rngDaysOfMonth As Range, rng As Range
Dim lngTargetRow As Long, lngTargetCol As Long
Dim wks As Worksheet

'Set references
Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

'Collect mobile number and day of month from user
strMobileNumber = CStr(InputBox("Enter Your Mobile Number"))
strDayOfMonth = CStr(InputBox("Enter todays Date - e.g 21  for 21/03/2015"))

'Stop the script if input is blank
If Trim(strMobileNumber) = "" Or Trim(strDayOfMonth) = "" Then
    Call ClientNotRegistered
    Exit Sub
End If

'Find the appropriate row by matching mobile number
Set rngMobileNumbers = wks.Range("D:D")
Set rng = rngMobileNumbers.Find(What:=strMobileNumber, LookAt:=xlWhole)
If rng Is Nothing Then
    Call ClientNotRegistered
    Exit Sub
End If
lngTargetRow = rng.Row

'Find the appropriate column by matching day of month number
Set rngDaysOfMonth = wks.Range("7:7")
Set rng = rngDaysOfMonth.Find(What:=strDayOfMonth, LookAt:=xlWhole)
If rng Is Nothing Then
    Call ClientNotRegistered
    Exit Sub
End If
lngTargetCol = rng.Column

'Write a "P" in the resulting cell
wks.Cells(lngTargetRow, lngTargetCol) = "P"
MsgBox "Client Checked In"

End Sub

'DRY solution for not found
Public Sub ClientNotRegistered()
    MsgBox "Client Not Registered"
End Sub
```